# processing.js unexpected identifier at if()

Tags: javascript, identifier, processing.js

I just can't seem to find the mistake, but when I remove the if statements it runs fine. The code is quite short so it should be easy to find the problem.

```
int zw1;
int zw2;
int px = 100;
int py = 100;
int ppx = px + random(-20, 20);
int ppy = py + random(-20, 20);
int cx;
int cy;
int xrand = 50;
int yrand = 50;
int opacity = 49;
frameRate(30);
background(74, 71, 74);
int timetoclear = 0;

int x0 = 0;
int y0 = 0;
void setup() {
    size(400, 400);

}
void draw() {

    cx = px + random(-xrand, xrand);
    cy = py + random(-xrand, xrand);

    // fill(74, 72, 74,5);
    // rect(-10,-10,1000,1000);

    //cx = mouseX;
    //cy = mouseY;  
    if (cx <= 0) {
        cx = 0;
    }
    if (cx >= 400) {
        cx = 400;
    }
    if (cy <= 0) {
        cy = 0;
    }
    if (cy >= 640) {
        cy = 640;
    }

    stroke(30 + random(-100, 100), 195 + random(-100, 100), 201, 60);

    fill(30 + random(-100, 100), 195 + random(-100, 100), 201, 50);

    triangle(ppx, ppy, px, py, cx, cy);

    ppx = px;
    ppy = py;
    px = cx;
    py = cy;
}
```

Throws:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Comment: Please include the exact error message.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier

Comment: how is that JavaScript ?

Comment: Thats not the full error, it'll give you a line number and/or column as well.

Comment: shouldn't `framerate` and `background` be in the `setup` function?

Comment: @TomaszLewowski Please notice the [tag:processing.js] tag.

Comment: Turns out my IDE is bugged :/ but Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me if I run it here: http://processingjs.org/tools/processing-helper.html

How exactly are you running your code?

I highly recommend programing in Java mode and then switching to JavaScript mode only for exporting. This will catch all the little errors you have, such as:

- You shouldn't have calls like `frameRate()` and `background()` and `random()` before the `setup()` function is called. Move those inside the `setup()` function.
- The `random()` function returns a `float` value, but you're storing it in an `int` variable. JavaScript won't complain, but it will cause weird behaviors.

Answer (score -1):

Don't know why this failed but you can try this as a workaround:

```
cx = Math.max(0, Math.min(400, cx));
cy = Math.max(0, Math.min(640, cy));
```

instead of

```
if (cx <= 0) {
    cx = 0;
}
if (cx >= 400) {
    cx = 400;
}
if (cy <= 0) {
    cy = 0;
}
if (cy >= 640) {
    cy = 640;
}
```